# Train complicated nn models with tf.eager (better with TF2 symbolic support)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, eager

Is there (more or less) simple way to write a complicated NN model so it will be trainable in the eager mode? Are there examples of a such code?

For example, I want to use the `InceptionResnetV2`. I have the code created with `tf.contrib.slim`. According to this link, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16182 , slim is deprecated and I need to use `Keras`. And I really can't use a slim code for training with eager because I can't take the list of variables and apply gradients (ok, I can try to wrap model into the `GradientTape` but not sure what to do with regularization loss).

Ok, let's try `Keras`.

```py
In [30]: tf.__version__                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[30]: '1.13.1'

In [31]: tf.enable_eager_execution()

In [32]: from keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2 import InceptionResNetV2

In [33]: model = InceptionResNetV2(weights=None)
...
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_applications/inception_resnet_v2.py in InceptionResNetV2(include_top, weights, input_tensor, input_shape, pooling, classes, **kwargs)
    246 
    247     if input_tensor is None:
--> 248         img_input = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    249     else:
    250         if not backend.is_keras_tensor(input_tensor):
...
RuntimeError: tf.placeholder() is not compatible with eager execution.
```

Doesn't work by default.

In this tutorial they say that I need to make my own class of a model and maintain variables by myself https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_training#define_the_model. I'm not sure that I want to do it for Inception. Too many variables to create and maintain. It's like returning back to old versions of `TF`, in days when even slim didn't exist.

In this tutorial networks are created using `Keras` https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_training_walkthrough#create_a_model_using_keras but I doubt that I can easily maintain complicated structure in a such way, by only defining model without using it with `Input`. For example, in this article, if I understand correctly, author initialize keras `Input` and propagate it through the model (which causes `RuntimeError` when used with Eager, as you seen earlier). I can make my own model by subclassing the model class as here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model . Oops, in this way I need to maintain layers, not variables. It seems as almost the same problem to me.

There is an interesting mention of `AutoGrad` here https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/autograph#keras_and_autograph . They only overwrite `__call__`, so it seems like I don't need to maintain variables in this case, but I didn't test it yet.

---

So, is there any simple solution?

Wrap slim model in `GradientTape`? How can I then apply reg loss to the weights?

Track every variable by myself? Sounds a little bit painful.

Use `Keras`? How to use it with eager when I have branches and complicated structure in the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first approach is probably the most common. This error:

> RuntimeError: tf.placeholder() is not compatible with eager execution.

is because one cannot use a `tf.placeholder` in eager mode. There is no concept of such a thing when executing eagerly.

You could use the [`tf.data` API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets) to build a dataset for your training data and feed that to the model. Something like this with the datasets replaced with your real data:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

model = tf.keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2.InceptionResNetV2(weights=None)

model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy)

### Replace with tf.data.Datasets for your actual training data!
train_x = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.random.normal((10,299,299,3)))
train_y = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.random.uniform((10,), maxval=10, dtype=tf.int32))
training_data = tf.data.Dataset.zip((train_x, train_y)).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

model.fit(training_data)
```

This approach works as is in TensorFlow 2.0 too as mentioned in your title.